# Barra de Progresso acompanhar o texto do input

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3

Bom estou iniciando no Bootstrap e estou com uma duvida se é ou não possível isso que estou querendo. Tenho um `textarea` onde o mesmo deve limitar o conteúdo a 300 caracteres o mesmo já esta funcionando:

```
$(function(){
   $(".maxlength").keyup(function(event){
     var target    = $("#content-countdown");
     var max        = target.attr('title');
     var len     = $(this).val().length;
     var remain    = max - len;
     if(len > max)
     {
       var val = $(this).val();
       $(this).val(val.substr(0, max));
       remain = 0;
     }
     target.html(remain);
   });
});
```

Html:

```
Restam <span id="content-countdown" title="300">300</span>Caracteres) 
<textarea name="texto" id="content" class="maxlength" maxlength="300" cols="60" rows="5"></textarea>
```

Só que gostaria que ao invés do numero ir diminuindo, a barra de progresso ir aumentando conforme o texto fosse sendo digitado e se atingir os 100% (300 caracteres) bloqueasse mais qualquer digito. Alguma ideia ou forma mais simples de fazer isso?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No HTML5 existe um elemento chamado `progress`, você pode usar ele para atingir seu objetivo:

```js
$(function(){
$(".maxlength").keyup(function(event){
document.getElementById("progress").value = $(this).val().length;
var target    = $("#content-countdown");
var max        = target.attr('title');
var len     = $(this).val().length;
var remain    = max - len;
if(len > max)
{
var val = $(this).val();
$(this).val(val.substr(0, max));
remain = 0;
}
target.html(remain);
});
});
```

```css
progress {
background-color: #f3f3f3;
border: 0;
height: 18px;
border-radius: 9px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Restam <span id="content-countdown" title="200">200</span>Caracteres)<br/>
<textarea name="texto" id="content" class="maxlength" maxlength="200" cols="60" rows="5"></textarea><br/>
<progress id="progress" max="200"></progress>
```

Comment: muito pratica essa funcao, achei que ia ser bastante complicado isso, parabens

Comment: Pelo fato desse elemento progress ser HTML5, não funcionará em alguns navegadores mais antigos.... so tenha isso em mente

Comment: Uma sugestão é usar `keypress` ao invés de `keyup`. No caso do *keyup* a *view* será atualizada somente quando o usuário deixar de apertar alguma tecla, se ele manter a tecla pressionada não acontecerá nada.